# Looping an array together with a jquery hover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, triggers, hover

I'm trying to... God, this is hard to explain.

I got an array called 'triggers' with these variables:

"#1_trigger","#2_trigger","#3_trigger"

And inside a jQuery each(), I create another variable called 'targets' that copies everything from 'triggers' and replaces all _trigger to _target. I then append the 'triggers' to anchor IDs, and 'targets' to hidden div IDs.

What I want to do, is this: When hovering a _trigger, the _target will show up. I've managed to make it work with only one variable, but not with multiple.

As I said, it's kind of hard to explain what I want to do in text, so here's a demo and my progress so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/WJWe3/6/

I've been stuck with this one for too many hours now, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st, do not name them with a `#` since you use that in the actual id. (*you can add the # in when you need to seek them with jquery*)

After that step the code you need is

```
$("#experiment a").hover(function(){
   $( '#' + this.id.replace('_trigger', '_target') ).show();

}, function(){
   $( '#' + this.id.replace('_trigger', '_target') ).hide();
});
```

This should be outside of the each loop since it automatically finds the relevant target.

You were also missing a sign `=` at the point that you assigned the `id` to the divs.

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/WJWe3/14/

Comment: Thank you so much for learning me all those things, and thank you for the working demo. The `=` sign was kind of embarrassing, haha.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?
http://jsfiddle.net/WJWe3/11/

Answer (score 0):

Here's another that works....  Just for fun.

http://jsfiddle.net/WJWe3/18/

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Using Firefox 4. Nothing happening when hovering.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Forgot to save a change.  Edited above.

Comment: Thank you for answering and helping me out! Will this apply to all anchors on the specific page? :)

Comment: As I've written it, yes.  I was too lazy to wrap it in a container or reference a specific class, which you'd of course want to do.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `id` for an element, it should not start with `#`. It's only when you use it as a selector in jQuery that it starts with `#`.

However, you don't even need to use the id. Create the `a` and `div` element as objects instead of as a string, then you can hook up the `hover` event directly to the link, and access the `div` directly, instead of trying to find it after adding it to the page.

[jsfiddle.net/WJWe3/16/](http://jsfiddle.net/WJWe3/16/)

```
var triggers = ["1_trigger", "2_trigger", "3_trigger"];

jQuery.each(triggers, function(i, val) {
    var target = $('<div/>', { className: 'hidden' }).text('You found me!');
    var link = $('<a/>', { href: '#' }).text(val).hover(function(){
        target.stop().fadeTo("normal", 1.00);
    }, function(){
        target.stop().fadeTo("normal", 0.00);
    });;
    $("#experiment").append(link).append(target).append("<br/>");
});
```

Comment: Woah, that's a really clever way to do it. Thank you very much for that demo, learned me a lot!

Comment: Watch those appends though!  You'd really want to append them to a detached element or a document fragment and then append the one big item at the end!

Answer (score 0):

here's how i would do this
http://jsfiddle.net/WJWe3/15/

```
<div id="experiment">
    <p><a>test 1</a> <span class='hidden'>hidden 1</span></p>
    <p><a>test 2</a> <span class='hidden'>hidden 2</span></p>
    <p><a>test 3</a> <span class='hidden'>hidden 3</span></p>
</div>
```

...

```
$('#experiment a').hover(
    function(){ 
        $(this).siblings('span').stop().fadeTo("normal",1); 
    },
    function(){ 
        $(this).siblings('span').stop().fadeTo("normal",0); 
    }
);
```

Comment: That's cool! I didn't know it could be that simple. Not really what I was looking for to my project, but something to save for later. Thanks a lot!